# The DOS effective mass

Tags: experimental-physics, solid-state-physics, mass, semiconductor-physics, density-of-states

If we consider the spin-orbit coupling in semiconductors, it is known that the degeneracy of the valance band is lifted up and we got 2 sub-bands the light hole and the heavy hole that are still degenerate at $k=0$ ($\Gamma$) so the DOS effective mass holes are just :
$m^*=(m_{hh}^{3/2}+m_{lh}^{3/2})^{2/3}$
but under a mechanical tensile the light hole band is shifted a little bit up so these sub bands are no longer degenerate at $k=0$
my question is what is the new DOS effective mass of holes?

Comment: Is this true for all semiconductors or only for Zinc-blend structure (like Si or GaAs)?